# Access childByAutoID key from child

Tags: swift, firebase

I have a Firebasestructure like this:

```
...    
  "objects" : {
    "-M2ToRL-DOIL5B7Kq1JH" : {
      "name" : "Orange",
      "weight" : 50,
      "color" : "Orange",
      "objectID" : "-M2ToRL-DOIL5B7Kq1JH"
    },
    "-M2U20-rpaaWBWnXjirx" : {
       "name" : "Banana",
      "weight" : 20,
      "color" : "Yellow",
      "objectID" : "-M2U20-rpaaWBWnXjirx"
    }
  },
```

I want to access the `childByAutoID` key. I have a query like this, but it results in nothing..

```
ref?.child("objects").queryOrdered(byChild:"name").queryEqual(toValue: name).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

                if snapshot.exists() {
                    print(snapshot)
                    let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
                    var key = ""
                    key = value?["objectID"] as? String ?? "Error"

                } else {

                    return
                }

            }, withCancel: {(Error) in
                print(Error.localizedDescription)
            })
```

I have also tried to get `value.key` but unsuccessful. How can I ket the key, either from the child itself, or from the `objectID` value stored ?

Comment: Have you tried the answer?

Comment: There's no reason to use that structure. Query for the node via it's 'name' property and then `snapshot.key` will be the objectID you want.

Comment: @Jay The reference is at node `objects`, if OP does `snapshot.key` then they will get `objects` and not the `childByAutoID`

Comment: @PeterHaddad Correct. My comment was not clear. I was referring to getting the key from the snapshot when iterating over the child nodes as shown in my answer. Good catch. Sorry. My suggestion was really to not duplicate the key within each child as it's not needed.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to retrieve the value `"-M2ToRL-DOIL5B7Kq1JH"` then you need to iterate to access it:

```
ref?.child("objects").queryOrdered(byChild:"name").queryEqual(toValue: name).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
             for child in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot]{
                print(child.key);
                if snapshot.exists() {
                    print(snapshot)
                    let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
                    var key = ""
                    key = value?["objectID"] as? String ?? "Error"

                } else {

                    return
                }
             }

            }, withCancel: {(Error) in
                print(Error.localizedDescription)
            })
```

Since your reference is at node `objects`, then to access the key you use a for loop and then use the property `key`

Check here for more info:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasedatabase/api/reference/Classes/DataSnapshot#key

Answer (score 0):

If you're using childByAutoId as a key, there's generally no reason to duplicate that data within the node as you can access the key directly.

For example

```
ref?.child("objects").queryOrdered(byChild:"name").queryEqual(toValue: name).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
    if snapshot.exists() == false {
        print("none found, returning")
        return
    }

    let allResults = snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot]
    for snap in allResults {
        print(snap.key) //prints each child key
    }
```